# executing action from a button in an XML layout through Dialog in Android

Tags: android, button, dialog, dismiss

I have the following XML layout file, ***HELPME.XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
android:id="@+id/fVal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#CC0000"
android:text="Function:" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/eVal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#CC0000"
android:text="Error Control:" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/hDesc"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="BLAH" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="12dp"
android:text="" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/closeButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the bit from the MainFile.java which calls this XML layout in a Dialog box:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case 1:
//Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Help is Here...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//openHelpWindow();
final Dialog d = new Dialog (MainActivity.this);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
d.setContentView(R.layout.helpme);
d.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_help);
d.setTitle("Color Finder Help");
d.setCancelable(true);

// **********************************************************
// EDIT - FIXED CODE
// This closes just the Dialog window...

        Button btn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
//******************************************************************


d.show();
break;

case 2:
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "About this app...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

//case 3:
// Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exiting app...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// System.exit(0);
// break;
}

return true;
}
```

Because i have my custom "Close Window" button in the xml layout, and because its being displayed as part of the layout in the Dialog Window which opens up from a menu option choice... how can i create an action for the button which will dismiss the dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to override the onclick listener for the button.  Then you can close the dialog like normal.

Comment: I tried to add an onClick listener above the d.show() but when i ran the program it just Force Closes. Where would i call that? Would be kind enough to tell me? Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html this shows how to add a yes and no plus the onclick listener. Go to the section about adding a button

Comment: Thank you for the link. I already checked the Yes, No. Cancel, etc button action within the Dialog. But i am using a cutom button from the layout which allows the user to click to exit the dialog. Am i being a little clearer? Thanks

Comment: d.setCancelable(true);
// EDIT - FIXED CODE
// This closes just the Dialog window...

        *** Button btn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            }); ***
    d.show();